# PHP - Regex to remove quotes and add braces?

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

Well, I hate to admit it but I have a hard time with REGEX, I could never find a decent tutorial on how expressions should be set up.

So say I have something like this

```
context['something']
```

and I want to change all occurrences to

```
context[something]
```

Then I have

```
' . $var . '
```

and I want to change all occurrences to

```
{var}
```

This is the current concept but I am having trouble with the regex part. I am using str_replace but with language changes I don't think it would stable enough that way.

Here is my attempt.

```
$codes = array (
         '/(\' \. \$)(.+)( \. \')/',
        '/(\[\')(.+)(\'\])/'
);
$html = array (
        '{\\2}',
        '[\\2]',
);
$data = preg_replace($codes, $html, $data);
```

It works until you get allot of them in a file and then it goes bad.

This is the current setup

```
// these are temp need a better replace system
$data = str_replace("' . $", "{", $data);
$data = str_replace(" . '", "}", $data);
$data = str_replace("<?php", "", $data);
$data = str_replace("?>", "", $data);
$data = str_replace('context[\'forum_name\']', 'context[forum_name]', $data);
```

Just need a proper way to comment these so they can be converted back later on during save.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your matches **non-greedy**.

Change

```
.+
```

to

```
.+?
```

[**It works!!**](http://www.ideone.com/vRLeT)

**Explanation:**

The quantifier `+` is greedy by default.

Consider the regex `\[(.+)\]` which tries to match and capture everything between the `[` and `]`.  On the input `[foo]` it works fine and `foo` is captured. But on the input `[foo] and [bar]` it'll capture `foo] and [bar` !!! This is the greedy behavior in action which makes `+` to consume as much as it can. By making the match non-greedy `\[(.+?)\]` we tell `+` to consume as less as it can but still trying to match. So in this case with the same input it'll capture `foo`.

**Some tips:**

There is no real need of the 1st and the 3rd group in your regex: `'/(\' \. \$)(.+)( \. \')/'`. So you can drop the 1st and 3rd pair of `(...)`. If you just want to group use `(?:..)` rather than `(..)` which is used for grouping + capturing.

The use of `\\n` in the replacement part is discouraged. It should be used only as back-reference in the regex. To use capture groups in the replacement part use `$n`.

[Program with above changes](http://www.ideone.com/ZgMso)

Answer (score 1):

I found [this tool](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) extremely helpful when learning regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one:

```
preg_replace("/context\['([^\']+)'\]/", "context[$1]", "context['bob']");
```

instead of using a non-greedy match, we just look for anything that's not a quotation mark.

And the other:

```
preg_replace("/' . [$]([^ ]+) . '/", '{$1}', '\' . $foo . \'');
```

This one's a bit trickier. We have to trap the $ in a set so it's not treated as the end-of-string character. And the {$1} has to be in single quotes so PHP doesn't interpret it + the braces as a variable.